# homepage olderposts link showing page not found

Tags: plugins, permalinks, pagination, 404-error, options

I am using WordPress 3.5.1 version, now I had a problem with `olderposts` link present at bottom of homepage. it is ok with rest of the category pages.

I am working on this problem since last two days, please somebody help me
i changed the `settings > reading`, changed `htaccess` but the problem was not solved.

I deactivated all the plugins and it didn't solve the problem.
i need somebody to help me.
my permalink structure is: `http://www.orclage.com/sample-post/`

my website name:
http://www.orclage.com

when i click olderposts the page is moving to
http://www.orclage.com/page/

Comment: Could you show us your .htaccess file content?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: That looks like a cache issue. Try empty cache and/or reset any cache service

Comment: @TweetPressFr ya i already cleared it :(